# Windows Universal application halts at CreateFileAsync()

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am working on Universal application Windows 10 in C# where I am creating several files in documents library folder during different thread processes.

```
var folder = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("TestApplication", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(String.Format("{0}.ref", tableName), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

After some successful attempts, my application gets halted at above line (CreateFileAsync). I put debugger but it just get halted and does not show any result or exception.

Can you please suggest what is the best way to mitigate it?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting use CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists in the CreateFileAsync function call

Comment: It did not make any difference.

Comment: The same access denied issue, I am also facing. Look this article may be we should not use document library as general purpose file storage area for an application. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/05/09/dealing-with-documents-how-not-to-use-the-documentslibrary-capability-in-windows-store-apps/

Comment: I have already defined Documents Library in manifest as capability.

Comment: I can't see any problem from your posted code, how many files did you created when app halted? Do you know that you can't publish a windows store app that specifies the documentsLibrary capability? If you try to create files in your app's local folder, will the same problem happen?

Comment: I will try it out.